# Different cookies on each page [puppeteer]?

Tags: puppeteer

How can I use different cookies with the same name and on the same URL for each page in the puppeteer library?

Comment: Have you tried anything? There's a [`page.setCookie()`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.setcookie) method you can call on each page.